# Shell script - How to export a script as a string?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a large shell script I'm trying to append to bashprofile on VM bootup:

I want this script to get *appended* to the `bashrc` file. I've tried the following:

```
read -d '' load_script << EOF
// code here
EOF
```

but it starts evaluating the variables automatically, I just want to push this script into the bashrc file. How can I do this?

### Script

```sh
writer_endpoint=$(aws neptune describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier redacted | jq .DBClusters[0] | jq .Endpoint | tr -d '"')
reader_endpoint=$(aws neptune describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier redacted | jq .DBClusters[0] | jq .ReaderEndpoint| tr -d '"')
writer_endpoint_status=$(awscurl https://$writer_endpoint:8182/status --service neptune-db | jq .status)
reader_endpoint_status=$(awscurl https://$reader_endpoint:8182/status --service neptune-db | jq .status)
cat << EOF

                +==========+===============+
                | Endpoint | Health Status |
                +==========+===============+
                | Reader   | $writer_endpoint_status     |
                +----------+---------------+
                | Writer   | $reader_endpoint_status     |
                +----------+---------------+

********************************************************************************************************
Welcome to the bastion host, used to debug connectivity and queries against the Neptune graph DB.
********************************************************************************************************

[Reader Endpoint]:
$reader_endpoint

[Writer Endpoint]:
$writer_endpoint

[Example - Check status of reader replica]:
awscurl https://$writer_endpoint:8182/status --service neptune-db

*******************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: What about `source filename.sh` in your bashrc?

Comment: Seems like you missed a part of your code. There is no closing `EOF`. Anyways, a [literal HereDocument](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) should do the trick. Write `<< 'EOF'` instead of `<< EOF`.

Comment: @Arount How can I cat these contents to a file?

Comment: @John what do you mean by "cat"? read?

Comment: Like if I "source filename.sh" I need to first create the file based on these contents. But I'm having issues with escaping everything, etc.

Comment: @Socowi, I can try this. I have two spots where I use << EOF. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Seems like I'm still having the same issue. Can you try showing it via an answer?

Comment: ahhh I am getting closer now with the literal 'EOF'

Comment: I'm trying to escape the EOF that is in the string

Comment: `<<EOF` should be `<<'EOF'` if you want the text to be literal. I see that Socowi pointed that out earlier.

Comment: It still seems the final EOF (which should be in the string) cannot be escaped. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be escaped? Quote only the starting sigil.

Comment: If the concern is that you have two different heredocs (f/e, embedding one inside the other), just pick a different sigil instead of using `EOF`. Literally any string will work. For example, you can use `<<'OUTER'` and `<<'INNER'`, terminated by `INNER` and `OUTER`.

Comment: I have two EOF in the script. Updated the OP. There is an EOF embedded in the string that needs to be escaped

Comment: Ah, that's what I needed, thanks!!